# Accessing Merge Settings via the GitLab API

Tags: merge, gitlab, gitlab-api

I would like to view and perhaps change the merge settings in GitLab (see the screenshot). How do I do this via the [API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/)?

---

[image: Screen shot of GitLab Merge settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is when creating a project there is a string named "merge_method" & "remove_source_branch_after_merge"

```
 merge_method
 remove_source_branch_after_merge
```

So this would be

```
GET /projects id/merge_method
```

for existing projects you can use

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#project-merge-method

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My problem is with existing repos.

Comment: Actually, the API you've pointed to `GET /projects` does return everything I need: `merge_method` and `remove_source_branch_after_merge`. I just didn't see it before. If you update your answer, I'm happy to award the bounty.

Comment: many thanks, i also missed the remove_source_branch_after_merge on that one

Comment: the answer has been adjusted